# What is ReturnURL in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, returnurl

What is Return URL in mvc3? When i write down my url in adress bar of the browser, at the append return url is automatically appended to it. How this happnes?

I provide the following url in adress bar

```
http://localhost:55875/admin
```

and after pressing enter it becomes

```
http://localhost:55875/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin
```

I have debugged the logic for Logon action method, but dont see any logi which is appending returnurl to the provided url? How did this happen?

Comment: Consider starting an 'empty' MVC application for learning the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an unauthenticated user tries to get into a section of your application which requires authentication, then returnUrl comes into the picture.The Url requested by the unauthenticated user is basically stored in `returnurl`.

for example below controller decorated with `Authorize` attribute :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

The login action grabs the value of this parameter and puts it in the ViewBag so it can be passed to the View.
The View then stores this value in the form as shown by this line of code in the View.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

The reason it is stored in the View is so that when the user does a Submit after entering their user name and password, the controller action that handles the post back will have access to this value.

Comment: If i want to make some pages like register available only for **UnLogged** users, what is the proper way to do such that?

Comment: we just need decorate our action method with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Comment: does `[AllowAnonymous]` redirect user if he was logged in?

Comment: You do not need to store the url in aViewBag since this is done automatically by the framework early on.

Answer (score 1):

Your application must be having Authentication for login which is handled by [Authorize] attribue. as user is not authenticated it returns to logon page with returnurl as admin

For more on AuthorizeAttribute [How to use authorize attribute on MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577266/how-to-use-authorize-attribute-on-mvc3)

Below is the standard action of login when you login above returnurl ie admin is passes as second parameter, depending on which user is redirected to the page using `return Redirect(returnUrl);`

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: How can I encode returnUrl by default, is there any setting in startup.cs or webconfig...

Answer (score 1):

Routing is one of the core concept of any `ASP.NET MVC` application. A `URL` of a `MVC` application is the combination of your `Application root URL` followed by `Controller` name and then `Action` to which request has been made e.g.

```
http://localhost:55875/{controller}/{action}/{optional parameters}
```

You probably have chosen new project with `Account Controller` and `Authorization` membership providers. As fellow members has mentioned, the `Authorize` attribute is probably the main reason you are being redirected to `logon` page.

From the documentation of [**Authorize attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.98).aspx#using_authorizeattribute):

> If an unauthorized user tries to access a method that is marked with
>   the Authorize attribute, the MVC framework returns a 401 HTTP status
>   code. If the site is configured to use ASP.NET forms authentication,
>   the 401 status code causes the browser to redirect the user to the
>   login page.

In browsers, whenever you hit enter key in address bar, browser always make a `GET` request to the server for resources.

That is what could have happened. Either your `Admin Controller` or its `Index()` method is decorated with `[Authorize]` action filter attribute e.g.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    ///<summary>
    /// This view will open whenever you make a HTTP GET request to your Admin
    /// controller without providing any action method name in request explicitly. 
    /// Because it is decorated with Authorize attribute, any user who has not logged in 
    /// will be redirected to the login page...
    ///</summary>
    [Authorize]    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You may wonder **why did application redirected to login view?**

This is because by default this action has been set in your application inside your `web.config` file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon"/>
</authentication>
```

MVC leverages the power of built-in authentication logic and redirects the user to view that has been set under `loginUrl`.

Try removing the `[Authorize]` action filter just **for a change** and see what happens. In the end it is your business logic to decide on which views you need to have only authorize or anonymous access.

However, you may also take a look at [AllowAnonymous attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx). It allows you to skip authorization for a perticular `contoller` or `action`.

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Skips Authorization..
    ///</summary>
    [AllowAnonymous]    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Only allows authorize access...
    ///</summary>        
    public ActionResult Secure()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can customize/override the behavior of these action filters as well.

Notice, `[Authorize]` has been added to `controller` itself if you have selected the project with internet and membership providers which will make all the actions inside this authorized except those with `[AllowAnonymous]` filter (if exists).

[**This article has good overview of Action filters in MVC**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First: you are trying to access an authorized page so every time you are trying to access this page the application automatically redirect you to login page

Second: how this happened?
in web.config file you can find a section for authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms"  >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon"/>
</authentication>
```

this section says that each time you are trying to access authorized page you will be redirected to this page and since its forms authentication so you will be redirected to this page

another thing you may using `Authorize` an `AuthorizeAttribute` which tells the application that the following `ActionResult` can't be accessed by anonymous users you can use this attribute in `class` level or `ActionResult` level as follows

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController 
{
}
```

Or

```
public class HomeController 
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```