# C#, ASP.NET - Restricting Access to Controller Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm constructing an ordering system of sorts that requires users to log in before proceeding to the main ordering part of the website. For example, I have a login controller that (if the user exists in the database) assigns their ID and UserName to a session.

```
public ActionResult Login(AccountAccess userObj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (SC_DBEntities db = new SC_DBEntities())
        {
            var accountObj = db.Users_Account.Where(u => u.Account_UserName.Equals(userObj.Account_UserName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (accountObj != null)
            {
                var accessObj = db.Users_Access.Where(a => a.Account_ID.Equals(accountObj.Account_ID) && a.Access_Password.Equals(userObj.Access_Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (accessObj != null)
                {
                    Session["Account_ID"] = accountObj.Account_ID.ToString();
                    Session["Account_UserName"] = accountObj.Account_UserName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View(userObj);
}
```

What I want to do from here is block out access to other method actions if that Session is null. So for example, if they want to access the products page but they are not logged in, the will be redirected to the login page.

I'm still reasonably new to ASP.NET so if there is a more efficient way of achieving this effect other than Sessions, please let me know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231751/authorize-filter-and-authentication are some good places to start. Basically, use an authorization action filter to determine whether or not to grant access.

Comment: Technically `Identity` is supposed to be better than Sessions, however I use Session too and they work for their intended purpose.  All you need is an else to handle when a user is not found after your if... is that all you are asking?

Comment: @Rinktacular, Not quite. What I mean is say we have someone using the website but they have not yet logged in. From the homepage, the can choose how they want to order and access the login and registration pages. What I'm trying to achieve is: say we have someone looking at that homepage who has not yet logged in. They click on the ordering link but instead of being transferred to the ordering page, they are transferred to the login page. Essentially, I'm trying to stop people who haven't logged in from accessing other controller methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not use a ActionFilterAttribute?

```
    public class CheckSession: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           var MySession = HttpContext.Current.Session

           if(MySession["Account_ID"] == null || MySession["Account_UserName"]== null)
           {
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Format("/Account/"));
           }  
        }
    }
```

Then all you have to do is put it on your controller action - Can also put it on the controller to check all inside that controller:

```
[CheckSession]
public ActionResult Purchase()
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely what I'm looking for. Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want for a controller or a specific action, you should use custom filter or attributes ( In your case authorization attribute ).

Please have a look to this good tutorial to begin : https://www.codeproject.com/articles/577776/filters-and-attributes-in-aspnet-mvc

After that, you just need to google :  **authorization attribute asp.net mvc**

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment, you can use Sessions for the purpose you are asking for. Assuming when a user logins, you store, say a username and their ID like you do above.  If you want to make sure someone is logged in before running an action just check to see if those Session variables are null nor not.

Going along with your Login Controller Code, suppose you have a purchase Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Purchase()
{
    //Check to see if these values have been assigned via Login Controller Action
    if(Session["Account_ID"] == null || Session["Account_UserName"] == null)
    {
         //If so, redirect to Controller Action where user can log into.
         RedirectToAction("Index", "Account")
    }
    else
    {
         //Make Purchase occur.
    }
}
```

[Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) is a newer and better login system, but has a pretty big learning curve in my experience.  Once you become more familiar with Sessions, I'd recommend to begin looking into Identity for future projects. Nothing "wrong" with Sessions, so for your purpose, the above code should work for actions you want users to be logged in to use.

Comment: OK that would work for what I'm looking at. I take it that would mean having to attach such an IF statement to every action that I want to restrict?

Comment: More or less... I am not sure how "good" this code is, but I have used this in my past projects as a way to handle logins and it was effective for the purpose I intended it to have :)

Comment: OK will look into it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: This work but you will need to copy/paste the code every time & every where that will you crazy and not good for maintening

Comment: @OrcusZ Then I suppose you can just make a public method and call that every time, easier to maintain then.

Comment: @Rinktacular That better, but the solution in asp.net mvc is to use attribute & filter, you can have a look to my answer or the one provided by Dylan

Comment: @OrcusZ Thanks, I knew my option felt wrong, happy to be corrected than to give bad information.  Thanks for your answer, it helped me as well!