# Implementing Permission in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to Implement Permissions in my project.As the code is too complex and I want to give permission per user on very granular region.So for that i have decided that there would be a panel that is of Admin where the list of user would be displayed to him and then he would decide what actions permission must be given to the particular user.
Can you guy's suggest me any example fro this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exploit Authorize attribute of MVC

Its simple and easy to use

All you need is

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.OnAuthorization = "IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization filter called";
    }
}
```

This is just an example of how you will be doing.

For details refer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577776/Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC
[How to use authorize attribute on MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577266/how-to-use-authorize-attribute-on-mvc3)